# Count condition in Laravel eloquent collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have this part of my eloquent query in Laravel 8

```
$voters = Voter::where('municipality', $user->municipality)->select(['status','leader', 'position'])->get();
    for($i = 0; $i < $brgys; $i++){
        //$voters = $voters_municipalities->where('brgy', $barangays['brgy'][$i])->get();
        $brgy_leader_info = $voters->where('brgy', $barangays['brgy'][$i])->where('position', '=', 'Leader')->count();
        $brgy_bac = $voters->where('brgy', $barangays['brgy'][$i])->where('position', '=', 'BAC')->count();
        $brgy_bac_leader = $voters->where('brgy', $barangays['brgy'][$i])->where('position', '=', 'BAC Leader')->count();
        $brgy_precint_coordinator = $voters->where('brgy', $barangays['brgy'][$i])->where('position', '=', 'Precint Coordinator')->count();
        $brgy_voters_bucg_voters = $voters->where('brgy', $barangays['brgy'][$i])->where('position', '=', 'Voter')->where('status', 2)->count();
        $brgy_voters_bucg_members = $voters->where('brgy', $barangays['brgy'][$i])->where('position', '=', 'Voter')->where('leader','!=',0)->where('status', 2)->count();
        $brgy_voters_bucg_voter_no_leader = $voters->where('brgy', $barangays['brgy'][$i])->where('position', '=', 'Voter')->where('status', 2)->where('leader', 0)->count();
        $brgy_voters_bucg = $voters->where('brgy', $barangays['brgy'][$i])->where('status', 2)->count();
        $brgy_leader['brgy'] =$barangays['brgy'][$i];
        $brgy_leader['leader_count'] =  $brgy_leader_info;
        $brgy_leader['brgy_bac'] =  $brgy_bac;
        $brgy_leader['brgy_bac_leader'] =  $brgy_bac_leader;
        $brgy_leader['brgy_precint_coordinator'] =  $brgy_precint_coordinator;
        $brgy_leader['brgy_voters_bucg_voters'] = $brgy_voters_bucg_voters;
        $brgy_leader['brgy_voters_bucg_members'] = $brgy_voters_bucg_members;
        $brgy_leader['brgy_voters_bucg'] = $brgy_voters_bucg;
        $brgy_leader['brgy_voters_bucg_voter_no_leader'] = $brgy_voters_bucg_voter_no_leader;
        $leaders_count += $brgy_leader_info;
        array_push($brgy_leaders, $brgy_leader);
    }
```

inside in the for loop is my previous query the commented line but it took 20+ seconds to load depending on the amount of data. So I tried to move up outside the loop but still got maximum execution time error. Somebody I do not have idea how can I make this more faster.

Comment: How about setting the execution time unlimited? `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: @MONSTEEEER I need to make it more faster, lesser than 20 secs no need to set the time limit. I tried to google to filter the collection but no luck.

Comment: I tried to make a copy of the collection and put it into variable but still time limit exceed.

Comment: have you tried changing the eloquent query to query builder?
 
[Eloquent vs Query Builder Comparison](https://devsenv.com/tutorials/laravel-eloquent-vs-db-query-builder-performance-and-other-statistics) it has small significance but I think will help you lessen the query run time.

Comment: What is the value of $brgys in for($i = 0; $i < $brgys; $i++)

Comment: @SimonR an array of strings

Comment: $brgys is static array of string or it comes from database?

Comment: @RBC yes static array and it comes from my config file.

Comment: @EasyWay use Eloquent relationship & fetch with withCount method.

Comment: @NatvarsinhParmar-bapu I already fix it. answer below. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by putting the collection into a json array and from there the conditions works flawlessly.

```
$municipal_voters = Voter::where('municipality', $user->municipality)->select(['status','leader', 'position', 'brgy'])->get();
    $voters = json_decode($municipal_voters, true);
```